# What's the difference between "a lawyer" and a "solicitor"?

Tags: difference, british-english

What's the difference between a "lawyer" and a "solicitor"?

A type of lawyer in Britain and Australia who is trained to prepare cases and give advice on legal subjects and can represent people in lower courts:

Answer (score 1):

"Lawyer" is a general term for people of all grades and levels whose profession is the practice of the law, who hold a qualification. "Solicitor" is a particular kind of junior lawyer found in the UK and British Commonwealth, who carries out more routine duties such as handling legal matters on behalf of clients, including wills, divorce, property sales, starting legal action ("suing"), etc. In recent years solicitors have been allowed to represent clients in lower courts. Previously all court work was carried out by more senior and more qualified lawyers, called 'barristers'.

Comment: "Solicitor" is also used in many states of the US as a job category/title. Solicitor General is a high ranking position in the DOJ (Department of Justice) and also exists in some states' judiciary branch. Some states, not all, call their senior prosecutors "solicitors".